# Torque in a heavy and light Body

Tags: torque

Suppose we have two wheels attached to axis (each wheel has its own axis). One wheel is heavy compared to the other. The moment arm of force is same for the both wheels. A force F is applied on both the wheels. The applied force is also same for both wheels.

The light wheel will rotate fast compared to the heavy wheel. Will the torque for both wheels be same? Torque is also defined as "The turning effect of a body." But the turning effect of both the bodies is different here so, will their torque be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **It is same  if radius of axle  is same for both.**

Torque is defined as moment of force about axis of rotation as:

$$\tau=\vec r\times \vec F$$

$\vec r$ is the position vector of point of application of force from axis of rotation.

In your case it it $\tau=rF$ where $r$ is radius of axle of wheel.

Comment: Yes, i am taking everything same. Radius and Force is same for both the wheels. So, you are saying that torque will be same?

Comment: @MuhammadRafique: Sure the torque is same but not angular accelerations.Which depends on Moment of inertia of body.